# Connect products with configurable product in magento with PHP

Tags: magento, import

I am currently writing an import for magento products. The data are delivered in a huge XML file - so I can't use the CSV import, which seems to be delivered directly with magento.

It is possible to import simple products - but there are two kinds of products I have some problems with:

1. Different languages for a product (languages are bound to the storeview)
2. Configurable products, which have connected products

I have totally no idea how to solve the problems. I hope you can give me a clue!
I've created models with products and save them - this works. But I don't know how to add language versions and the configurable products.

Currently I've got this:

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$newProduct->setData('attribute_set_id', self::APP_ATTRUBITE_SET_ID);
$newProduct->setData('tax_class_id', self::APP_TAX_CLASS_ID);
$newProduct->setData('website_ids', array_keys(Mage::app()->getWebsites()));
$newProduct->setData('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$newProduct->setData('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE);
$newProduct->save();

$relatedProduct = clone $newProduct;
$relatedProduct->setData('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
$relatedProduct->setData('sku', $relatedProduct->getData('sku') . '-ABC');
$relatedProduct->save();
```

But this don't link the products to each other.

Comment: You might want to check uRapidFlow. http://www.unirgy.com//products/urapidflow/ It's a great module for importing large amounts of products.

Comment: Check MAGMI - it's free and a really powerful tool for importing products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial on web, which is a bit confusion but contains the solution to import configureable products.

http://www.danneh.org/2012/05/creating-products-programmatically-magento/